# iOS canOpenURL: how to return NO when no sim on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I use UIApplications' canOpenURL to check if the device can make phone call using "tel:" scheme, but it return YES when the app runs on iPhone **WITHOUT** sim, in this case, the phone cannot make call, but it still returns YES. Is there a way to check if the iPhone can really make call?

Thanks!

Comment: i dont think the standard API supports the checking of sim card availability. see prince answer, we assume you do the checking like the posted code in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Core Telephony's `CTCarrier`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html) to get the current carrier. Lack of a carrier probably means no coverage or SIM missing.

Comment: Thanks I know that method, but is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Not that I know of without jailbreaking. It sounds like it solves your problem, why can't you use it?

Comment: Additionally, CDMA phones don't need SIM cards to make calls.

Answer (score 2):

To check if the iPhone can really make call use this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]];
```

The method returns a BOOL, so check that for YES or NO.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was asking, this method returns YES even if the iPhone does not have a SIM(ie cannot make call).

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]];
```